# Trying to run Vite inside Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

I'm new in Docker and JS technologies so don't judje too hard. I'm trying to run `npm run dev` from node.js container (called npm). It goes right and shows that css and scripts are available at localhost:3009, but they're not.
Am I right that the problem is with node.js container, which is trying to restart all the time and doesn't exposes any ports? If yes, how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.
Here is my docker-compose.yml and vite.config.js

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - redis
      - mysql
      - mailhog
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: php
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - laravel

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:latest
    container_name: npm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
      - 3009:3009
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - 1025:1025
      - 8025:8025
    networks:
      - laravel
```

vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port: 3009
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like your `npm` container is actually doing anything, it just runs the `npm` wrapper and exits.  Is there a reason to declare processes like npm or composer as long-running Compose containers, or can you use a multi-stage build to collect all of the parts into a single self-contained image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "[--host](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host)" key starting your Vite

Answer (score 0):

This is the working config for me | vite / docker / windows

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hmr: {
            clientPort: 3000,
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },
});
```